# Count number of loop iteration

Tags: java

Here I have a simple method that finds all duplicate numbers using `HashMap`s. This only shows the numbers which are duplicated. I need to count the occurrence of each number as well. How can I implement my `for` loop to count the frequency of each number?

```
//driver

public class findDuplicates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = { 2, 3, 6, 5, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7, 7, 7, 4, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2 };
        dulicates(input);
    }

    public static void dulicates(int[] MyArray) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> HashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i : MyArray) {
            if (!HashMap.containsKey(i)) {
                HashMap.put(i, 1);
            } else {
                HashMap.put(i, HashMap.get(i) + 1);
            }
        }
        for (Integer i : HashMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("This has a duplicate: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i smell homework.

Comment: you're already counting the occurrences. The value in the map is the counts.  How are you finding the duplicates?  That should be enough as a hint.

Comment: My apologies I must have fat fingered it, it was not intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some methods of the `Map` interface that make this easy. One is `compute()`.

- if the value is null, initialize it to some value, otherwise process the existing value
- An example of the above is `compute(i, (k,v)-> v == null ? 1 : v + 1` which says if the `value` for the `key` is `null`, initialize to `1`, otherwise, add `1` to existing `value`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] input = {2,3,6,5,5,6,9,8,7,7,7,4,1,2,5,5,2};
    duplicates(input);
}
    
public static void duplicates(int[] myArray){
    Map<Integer,Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
    // perform a frequency count of the array
    for (int i : myArray) {
        freq.compute(i, (k,v)-> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
    }
    
    // now just print the duplicates and their count.
    System.out.println("Duplicates");
    freq.forEach((k,v) -> {
        if (v > 1) {
            System.out.printf("%s occurs %s times.%n", k,v);
        }
    });
}
```

Prints

```
Duplicates
2 occurs 3 times.
5 occurs 4 times.
6 occurs 2 times.
7 occurs 3 times.
```

Answer (score 5):

You already solved it, you just missed the iteration and check for values > 0.

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> kv : map.entrySet())
{
    if (kv.getValue()>0)
        System.out.println(kv.getKey()+" has "+ kv.getValue() +" duplicate(s)");
}
```

---

Based on this logic, consider to implement a **getter** method for your zipped string.

An example here, using a `map` that just contains duplicates(*just for fun*) and a single `set` that could help you identifying duplicates and storing uniques. Thanks to that, you could return an `int[]` without duplicates from the base array.

```
static int[] showDuplicatesAndGetCleanArray(int[] myArray) //pls change my name
{
    //myArray = {2,3,6,5,5,6,9,8,7,7,7,4,1,2,5,5,2};
    Set<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>(myArray.length);
    Map<Integer,Integer> dupMap = new HashMap<>(myArray.length);
    for (int i : myArray) 
    {
       if(uniques.contains(i))
          dupMap.put(i, dupMap.get(i)==null ? 1 : dupMap.get(i)+1);
       else
          uniques.add(i);   //else not required, I love useless micro-optimizations   
     }                                

    System.out.println("Total duplicates : [" + (myArray.length-uniques.size())+"]");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> kv : dupMap.entrySet())
         System.out.println("- {" + kv.getKey() + "} has " + kv.getValue() +
                            " duplicate" + (kv.getValue()>1 ? "s" : "") ); 

    return uniques.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

***Result:***

```
Total duplicates : [8]
- {2} has 2 duplicates
- {5} has 3 duplicates
- {6} has 1 duplicate
- {7} has 2 duplicates

/* returned  int[] => {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}  */
```

Answer (score 0):

As I feel this might be a homework, you should do some of the figuring our for yourself, so I will give to the basic idea but not the code. That is for you to figure out.

A hashmap allows you to use a key to access a value. So for each unique value found in the input.

Check if there is a element in the hashmap with that key, If not place a new element in the hashmap withe the value found as its key, and a 1 as its value.

Else if the there is an item in the hashmap with that key, pull the value out, increment it and put it back under that key.

Have your function end by returning the hashmap.